# Why is Sublime HTML Prettify not working

Tags: sublimetext2

I've installed Sublime-HTMLPrettify as shown here https://github.com/victorporof/Sublime-HTMLPrettify

but when I try and use the command (e.g. by right clicking on a selected section of HTML) it doesn't do anything.

Is there something I'm missing?

==== PLATFORMS

SublimeText 2

OS X 10.11.3 (15D21)

Node.js is at `/usr/local/bin/node` and I can access it from the CLI using `node`.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of **Sublime Text** you are using? and in which OS you have installed it?
For your *tag* I supposed **Sublime Text 2**.
Ensure you have [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js) on System Paths and take a note from the commands and configurations that the description file of [sublime-htmlprettify](/questions/tagged/sublime-htmlprettify) are only for **Sublime Text 3**

Hope this help you.